# JQuery UI Input Value Selection

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

update.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( "#items" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'searchforitem.php'
});
});
</script>
<div class="ui-widget"><input id="items" name="itemname" placeholder="Search Item here"></div>
```

searchforitem.php

```
<?php include_once 'dbcontroller.php';

//get search term
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

//get matched data from skills table
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM item,category,brand WHERE ((Partno LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%') OR (Description LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%') OR (Cname LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%') OR  (Cname LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%')) AND ((item.Bno=brand.Bno) AND (item.Cno=category.Cno)) ORDER BY Partno ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row['Partno']." ".$row['Bname']." ".$row['Description'];
}

//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Now what I want is that I want input `id="items"` to have value Part no only, But one can see all data in dropdown.

Hope I am able to tell you what I want to do.

Any Help would be great

**What I am doing in Searchforitem.php?**

I am displaying all data from Item Table, where term matches to SKU, Name, Description, Brand Name or category name

Now I am displaying all data but I want Input value to be only "Partno"
Is this possible?

Comment: in your query select only that specific column then : `SELECT Partno  FROM item,category,brand WHERE.............`

Comment: But I want to display everything related because how one can Identify Particular item without its description

Answer (score 1):

You need to make associative array with key "value" for partno to accomplish this.

```
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = [ "value" => $row['Partno'] , "bname" => $row['Bname'] , "description" => $row['Description']];
}
```

Comment: Actually It's showing only Partno http://prntscr.com/dla70i But I want like this http://prntscr.com/dla7yi to display all description & when we select it, Only Partno should be stored. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I need to use associative array with Key "value" for partno and "label" for all Information I need to display, Here is the code..

```
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = [ "value" => $row['Partno'] , "label" => $row['Partno']." ".$row['Description']." ".$row['Bname']." ".$row['Cname']];
}
```

And Thanks to Faiz99 for giving idea of associative array and using Key "value"